# Server error 500 on cpanel. Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, cpanel

Greeting everyone

I have moved my symfony project from localhost to cpanel. When i open the link it shows the content of config.php
http://example.com/symfony/web/config.php

But when i try to open 
http://example.com/symfony/web/app_dev.php/ i get an Server 500 error. I tried to comment out the if statement but i still get the Server 500 error.

Please help!

Here is my app_dev.php file content

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
umask(0000);
/*if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
 ||isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) 
 ||(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['my_ip_adress','127.0.0.1','fe80::1','::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
 ) {
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).'for more information.');
 }*/

/**
* @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader
*/
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: "shows the content of config.php" If you mean the source code is being displayed then your server is not configured to process php.  Or do you see a page indicating everything is fine?

Comment: It is not showing the source code. Configuration Checker it shows. Everything is ok with config.php. But app_dev.php is making that Server 500 error. I checked at var/logs/dev.log. I changed every "request_uri" that was http://localhost//symfony/web/app_dev.php/page1 for exapmle with http://example.com//symfony/web/app_dev.php/page1 and i am still getting the error. Maybe i should change something else. Any ides?

Comment: Does the server php version match your localhost version?  5.3 on the server can often cause problems with stuff developed under 5.4+.

Comment: the php server version is 5.4.

Comment: I apologize. The problem was with the server php version. Now it is php 5.5. Problem solved. Thanks.